# How can I reliably modify build configs and add compiler flags in C/C++ RPM files?

Tags: compiling, rpm, rpmbuild, compiler, rpm-spec

I need to change the build configuration of a large number of rpm files for testing purposes. I'm only speaking of C/C++ code here. I'm not necessarily looking to do automation, but I could use a hand in doing it even manually.

I'll use a specific example this time to make the question more clear. Say I have the rpm for Perl Compatible Regular Expressions library and the [specfile](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/pcre/raw/master/f/pcre.spec) has:

```
%configure \
%ifarch s390 s390x sparc64 sparcv9 riscv64
    --disable-jit \
%else
    --enable-jit \
%endif
    --enable-pcretest-libreadline \
    --enable-utf \
    --enable-unicode-properties \
    --enable-pcre8 \
    --enable-pcre16 \
    --enable-pcre32 \
    --disable-silent-rules
%{make_build}
```

And I want to add the compiler flags for AddressSanitizer, so I add this after `--disable-silent-rules`:

```
   CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -fsanitize=address -g3"
   CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -fsanitize=address -g3" \
   LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -fsanitize=address -g3" \
   LSAN_OPTIONS="verbosity=1:log_threads=1:log_pointers=1"
   ASAN_OPTIONS="detect_leaks=0"
```

Is this the best way to do this? I'm finding that sometimes, this does not work. In this case, I checked the output .sos and they do not have asan sections or `-g3` debug info... I'm looking for a reliable way to add in asan and debug info in this case, but this could apply to any such compiler flags. I could also try to do this manually, but I'd prefer to use the RPM tools so that I can reliably reproduce the exact build as specified in the RPM specfile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most universal way that would apply to most packages is customizing `optflags` macro.

You can create `$HOME/.rpmrc` and put your customized value for it.

To get the current value for our OS, you can first run:

```
rpm --eval %{optflags}
```

This will yield, for example on RHEL 8:

> -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wp,-D_GLIBCXX_ASSERTIONS -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-annobin-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fcf-protection

Copy-paste your result, while modifying parameters as needed, e.g. change `-g` to `-g3` and save it in `~/.rpmrc`.

Verify that you did everything correctly by running the above command again, to get the modified value.

Comment: Thanks. Is `optflags` automatically used by default for the CXX, C, and LDFLAGS or must I edit the specfile to use it?

Comment: `optflags` are automatically used in most cases. See [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/RPMMacros/#_macros_providing_compiler_and_linker_flags), for LDFLAGS you want `%{build_ldflags}`. The `optflags` macro is used by `rpmbuild`: it will set `CFLAGS` and `CXXFLAGS` as *environment* variables. Then `gcc` will honor the value of those environment variables. The only time it won't work is when a program has, e.g. `CFLAGS=` in its Makefile set explicitly. That time you would want to patch it so it is either completely removed or use `CFLAGS+=` to inherit environment.

Comment: Interesting and I appreciate you throwing in the info on LDFLAGS. This ended up working well, with a few modifications to the default optflags.